# Shell script to search files for identical text entries

Tags: shell, text-processing, duplicate

I need to write a script :

1. Take a directory with several text files. Can be a few up to ~1000.
2. All files contain an identifier on a given line (always the same line).
3. Identify which files have identifier that is NOT UNIQUE, i.e. Duplicated in other file(s) in the directory.
4. Output or save the list of duplicates

This is needed for a routine admin 'clean-up' of system generated files that SHOULD be unique but through user error may not be.

Comment: Please give an input file and the output that you are expecting. Also, please be advised that this is not a shell script writing site. You should probably tell what you have tried so far to get more help :)

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't do this with shell scripting. It's possible, but it's so much easier to do this in a scripting language like Perl or Python (just collect all the identifiers into a hash/dictionary).

Comment: @nneonneo - that's what I did after all, actually.

Comment: There are various ways of doing this but we need to know how to get the identifier for all of them. Is it the entire line X? The first word of it? The first numbers? How can we know? Please show us an example of the format we need to deal with.

Comment: That's a good point , @terdon, especially considering OP calls it a *given* line but doesn't give it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help on this. It looks like I have something to work with here ok, but I won't get a chance to test it for another day or two. To answer some of the questions:

Comment: - The ID will always appear on line 6 of plain text files.
- It occupies the line completely, no spaces, made up of letters, numbers and hyphens, here is an example: ID:XYZ-01234456789
- I’m not too concerned about the output format, but here’s a suggestion: a text file containing these entries line by line
FILENAME-A, FILENAME-B, FILENAME-C /these 3 contain same ids.
FILENAME-D, FILENAME-E /these 2 contain same ids
etc…

Answer (score 8):

Based on your comments above, and having noted that my test data is very similar to your actual data, I was able to verify this works:

```
grep -n '^ID.[^:-]*.[0-9][0-9]*$' |
sed -n 'h;s|\(.*\):6:\(ID.*\)|\2|p;g;s||\2:\1|p'
sort -u | 
sed 's|ID..*:||'
```

I `grep` the folder for lines beginning with `ID` and the rest, and because it finds multiple matching files and i asked for the matching line `-n`umbers `grep` prints:

```
[filename]:[matching line number]:[IDmatch]
```

I pass that to `sed` which saves copy of the line in the `h`old buffer then checks for the string `:6:ID` and, if found, deletes everything on the line up to `ID`. Then I `p`rint out the results.

Following that I `g`et back the buffer - overwriting my last edits in the process - and swap the locations on the line of `grep`'s match and its matching filename. So for every line `grep` prints of a line 6 match `sed` replaces it with:

```
[IDmatch]
[IDmatch]:[filename]
```

When this data is passed to `sort`it organizes the whole set by `ID` and because I ask it only for `-u`nique results it deletes all but one for repeated `IDmatch` only lines but retains the following `IDmatch:filename` lines. The next `sed` statement just cleans it up, rendering this:

```
ID00000000
ID00000000:file00
ID00000000:file10
...
ID00000000:file80
ID00000001
ID00000001:file01
ID00000002
ID00000002:file02
...
```

Like this instead:

```
ID00000000
file00
file10
...
file80
ID00000001
file01
ID00000002
file02
...
```

But that solution *will* break if a filename contains a `\n`ewline character, though the following won't. And I worked out how to put the following in a shell function so it doesn't have to globe twice - I'll paste it in here soon.

```
for f in * ; do
    sed '5!d;s|^|: "${'$((i=i+1))'}" |;q' "$f"
done |
sort -t' ' -k3 |
uniq -D -f2 |
sh -cx "$(cat)" -- * 2>&1
```

That should do it - so long as you substitute the `5` in the `sed` statement for whatever lines your ids are on. I think - and if I'm wrong let me know - this handles all cases otherwise.

For every file in the directory it increments a number by one and prints a line beginning with the string...

```
: "${[num]}" ...
```

...where `[num]` is an actual integer that it has just incremented by 1 and `...` is your unique id line.

It then pipes those lines out first to `sort` which treats the `<space>` character as a delimiter and sorts only the data from the third field on. The `|pipeline` continues next to `uniq` which also delimits on `<space>` and skips the first two fields of input while comparing its input and printing only `-D`uplicate lines. The next part is a little weird.

So rather than having to loop all the way through again and find out which file is which, I did the `[num]` thing as mentioned. When the `sh` shell process at the end of the `|pipeline` is passed the
results it only receives those numbers. But it has set its positional parameters already to the same glob we were iterating over while incrementing those numbers - so when it evaluates those numbers it will associate them with the files already in its positional array. That's all it does.

In fact - it barely even does that. Each positional parameter is preceded by the `:`null command. The only thing that shell process does is evaluate the variables passed to it - it never executes a single line of code. But I set it to `-x` debug mode and redirected its `stderr` to `stdout` so it prints all of the filenames.

I do it that way because it is much easier than worrying about weird filenames breaking the `sort | uniq` results. And it works very well.

I tested this with a dataset generated in the following way:

```
tr -dc '[:graph:]' </dev/urandom |
dd ibs=100 cbs=10 conv=unblock count=91 |
split -b110 --filter='
{   c=${FILE##%%*0} ; c=${c#file}
    sed "5cID000000${c:-00}"
} >$FILE' -ed - file ; rm *90*
```

*Please note the `rm` string above. I was getting a little sleepy and didn't really care to figure out why `file89` was being generated with only 102bytes and not 110bytes as the rest, so I rounded up into the 90s and then `rm`d it. Running the above will rm filenames matching that glob in the current directory and overwrite any files from `file00` - `file89`, but when used in a delegated test directory it is perfectly safe.*

...among others... And it worked for all.

That writes 90 files named `file[0-8][1-9]` each with 1-4,6-10 10-byte lines of random data and one unique ID on line 5 in every file. It also produces `file[0-8]0` wherein lines 5 are always `ID00000000`.

The output of the little function at the top run on this dataset looks like:

```
+ : file10 ID00000000
+ : file00 ID00000000
+ : file20 ID00000000
+ : file30 ID00000000
+ : file40 ID00000000
+ : file50 ID00000000
+ : file60 ID00000000
+ : file70 ID00000000
+ : file80 ID00000000
```

If for whatever reason you don't like the `+` symbols in the output just change `$PS4` for that last shell process. You add this in at the beginning of the last line to handle that:

```
PS4= sh ...
```

But you could alternatively set that to any string - or even executable bit of shell script if you like, and it will separate the filenames as you like. Basically you can use the prompt as an auto delimiter as you will. And that last shell process still has the filenames in its array - you can add commands to manipulate the data according to your preference.

Comment: This introduces a race condition by doing the glob twice. If for some reason a file is added between the first glob and the second (quite possible since the time difference will be significant for 1000+ files), then your indexes will be off. Better to do something like `set -- *` to make sure you are using the same list of files both times.

Comment: But @Graeme, they're in the same pipeline - they're concurrent. I should refactor it a little to also put them in the same shell, but that might slow it down. I dont believe the danger is as you say.

Comment: Yes, your right. My bad.

Comment: @Graeme - it is still a very valid point, though, i think, that both shells should be sourcing the same array as opposed to generating it independently, concurrently or not. ive been experimenting for an hour. Youve been missed, dude. Im playing around with `sh -nv` trying to get it to read out the file contents separated by the filenames.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the filenames have no spaces or newlines and that a GNU `uniq` supporting the `-D` option is available, this is really easy (change the number after `FNR==` to change the line of the identifier):

```
awk 'FNR==2 { print FILENAME,$0 }' * | sort -k 2 | uniq -Df 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Without the `-D` option for `uniq`, things quickly get more complicated, one way is to invert the output of `uniq -u` using `comm`:

```
awk 'FNR==2 { print FILENAME,$0 }' * | sort >/tmp/sorted_keys
sort -k 2 /tmp/sorted_keys |
  uniq -uf 1 | sort | comm -23 /tmp/sorted_keys - | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

To do this for files with any name, `perl` is probably the best option (change the number after `$.==` on line 1 to change the line of the identifier):

```
perl -ne 'push(@{$table{$_}}, $ARGV) if $.==2;
  $.=0 if eof;
  END {
    for my $val (values %table) {
      print join( "\n", @{$val} ) . "\n" if @{$val} > 1;
    }
  }' *
```

The idea is to index each filename by the identifier found in the file so that each identifier can be used to fetch an array of filenames. This way it is easy to print out each of these arrays that have more than one element.

#### Update

It is actually possible the use the same approach as above in `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==2 {
  i=table_sizes[$0]++;
  table[$0,i]=FILENAME
  }
  END {
    for (key in table_sizes) {
      if (table_sizes[key] > 1) {
        for (long_key in table) {
          if ( index(long_key, key SUBSEP) == 1 ) {
            print table[long_key]
            delete table[long_key]  # speed up next search
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }' *
```

The only issue is if the value of `SUBSEP` appears in any of the identifiers. Usually `SUBSEP` is a non-printing character (`0x1c`), so this won't be a problem in most text files. It can be changed as needed or the example could be adapted to real multidimensional arrays (eg `array[x][y]` instead of `array[x,y]`) in an `awk` that supports them like `gawk`.

Comment: He's back. But, so you know, my own answer handles any file name with just sort and uniq.

Comment: @mikeserv, I see that now. Should have read it more carefully before doing my own. I have added a pure `awk` solution, no GNU tools required [blows raspberry]. Although the same `comm` trick I used would work with yours too.

Comment: @graeme - I had a chance to test it just now, and the single awk solution does the trick. Filenames don't contain spaces, so no need for the perl solution. Thank you very much for the prompt response.

Answer (score 4):

I could give you something more specific if you explain your format but for the sake of argument, lets assume that your identifier is the 1st space-separated word on the 3rd line of each file. If so, you could do:

```
for f in *; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$f" $(awk 'NR==3{print $1}' "$f"); done |
 perl -F"\t" -lane '$k{$F[1]}{$F[0]}++; 
  END{
   foreach (keys(%k)){
     print "$_ : ", join ",",keys(%{$k{$_}}) if scalar (keys(%{$k{$_}})) > 0 }
  }'
```

#### Explanation

- `for f in *; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$f" $(awk 'NR==3{print $1}' "$f"); done` : this goes through all files (and subdirectories, if any) in the current directory and prints the name of the file, a tab (`\t`) and the 1st field of its 3rd line (the `awk` command).
- `perl -F"\t" -lane` : The `-a` flag makes `perl` act like `awk`, automatically splitting the input line into fields on the character given by `-F` and saving those fields into the `@F` array. The `-l` removes trailing newlines from each input line and adds one to each `print` call and the `-e` is the script that should be run.
- `$k{$F[1]}{$F[0]}++` : This saves the filename/identifier pairs in a hash of hashes where the identifier is the key of the first hash and the filename the key of the second. The resulting structure would look like this:

  ```
  $k{identifier1}{filename1}
  $k{identifier1}{filename2}
  $k{identifier1}{filenameN}
  ```
- The `END{}` block will be executed after the entire input has been read.
- The `foreach` loop goes through each key of the hash `%k` (the file names) and prints the identifier (`$_`, the key) and the list of keys of the subhash (`keys(%{$k{$_}}`).

I tested on a set of files created by this command:

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo -e "$RANDOM\nbar\n$i" | tee file$i > file${i}d; done
```

The above creates 5 pairs of files (file1/file1d through file5/file5d) with the same 3rd line. Running the command above on these files produces:

```
id2 : file2d,file2
id4 : file4,file4d
id5 : file5d,file5
id1 : file1,file1d
id3 : file3,file3d
```

Comment: @mikeserv 'cause it was just an example and I edited my actual output. Space removed and more details added.

Comment: That `tee` thing is cool. I've never thought to write out two files like that before - I always write to pipes and stuff. But what about `<tabs>` and `\n`ewlines and the rest in the filenames?

Comment: @mikeserv they will both cause problems. Spaces should be fine but tabs and newlines in the filename will indeed break this. I am assuming those won't be an issue since the files in question are "system generated".

Comment: Nevermind about the subfolders - I thought at first you were saying it was recursive - but you don't say that, just that it flat-references all files in the current directory - directory type or other wise of course. As for the other - 
that's a pretty good assumption I'd say - its the same one i made at least (and maybe I just got lucky that it handled those others anyway).